# Reemplazar con Ctrl + a

Tags: javascript, jquery

Acabo de validar un input text, pero al momento de hacer Ctrl + a y luego presionar cualquier carácter para que se reemplace, NO llega a suceder nada. Quisiera saber cuál es el motivo de este error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="texto" type="text">
</body>

<script>
    $("#texto").on("keypress", function(event){
        
        if(event.which > 47 && event.which < 58){
            return false;
        }

        if($(this).val().length == 5){
            return false;
        }
            
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: No es al escribir cualquier cosa, es al escribir 5 caracteres, entra en el segundo `if`, devuelve `false` y no te permite hacer nada. Si escribes menos de 5 sí te lo permite

Comment: ya veo, y cómo podría arreglarlo amigo @Rabegi

Comment: ¿Por qué motivo necesitas que ese `if` devuelva `false`?

Comment: solo era para limitar los caracteres, pero si hay otra manera, mucho mejor!!!

Comment: Te lo dejo como respuesta con el código incluido :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al tener una función que limita los caracteres del `input` de esa forma lo que le estás diciendo es que cualquier tecla que pulses cuando los caracteres sean 5 no haga nada.

Para limitar el tamaño máximo del `input` puedes hacerlo a través del mismo html con la propiedad `maxLength` igualada al número máximo de caracteres permitidos:

```js
$("#texto").on("keypress", function(event) {
  if(event.which > 47 && event.which < 58){
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="texto" type="text" maxLength="5">
```

Comment: WOW, pensaba que maxLength era solo para los textArea, gracias :)